# Order grep output by second token

Tags: bash, sorting, grep

I am grepping for log output in many log files. I want the output of the grep command to be ordered by the time, which is the second token of every log line. The log lines are preceded with the date in the following format:

```
[2019-Jan-18 09:46:40.385624]
```

The logs are only ever from today so ordering only by the time will suffice.

I am using the following command to grep for a string:

```
grep "needle" /path/to/logs/*
```

How can I order the output by ascending time? I have tried piping to the sort command

```
grep "needle" /path/to/logs/* | sort
```

but that only sorts by the filename.

Comment: How do you pipe `sort` with current `grep`?

Comment: grep "needle" /path/to/logs/* | sort

Comment: Try on this way: `grep "needle" /path/to/logs/* | sort -k2,2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force `sort` to sort second column you should use command like:

```
grep "needle" /path/to/logs/* | sort -k2
```

To use for sort **only** second column you should use it on this way:

```
grep "needle" /path/to/logs/* | sort -k2,2
```